# How to traverse a map by value

Tags: boost, stl, dictionary, traversal, bimap

Say there is a map: `typedef map<int, string> MyMap;`

I'd like to traverse it by the string, for example:

```
3 -> a
1 -> b
7 -> b
2 -> c
```

One way is to sort this map by its value. But I'm afraid this will have impact to find() efficiency (is it true?)

Another choice is to use `boost::bimap`. But, as you might notice, the value in MyMap is not unique, so bimap is not applicable here.

Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to use multiple values in boost.bimap: `multiset_of`

The data definition changed to:

```
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>
typedef boost::bimap<int, boost::bimaps::multiset_of<std::string> > MyMap;
```

Now I can traverse my data by either key or value.

Comment: If you don't want sorted traverse, you can make it unordered like `typedef boost::bimap<unordered_set_of<int>, unordered_multiset_of<std::string> > MyMap;` This will make the lookups much faster